# nodes created with newHazelcastInstance(config) not discovering each other?

Tags: hazelcast

in a test, I make 2 newHazelcastInstance and I notice that sometimes they appear as joined right after (as expected) or sometimes they appear as 2 separate single-node clusters..can you help me understanding why / how to fix it so they join all the time? The config is only about an iMap, the discovery is not touched (and I believe that multicast would be used normally, right?)
Thank you

Comment: Can you share some log outputs showing nodes creating 2 different clusters?

Answer (score 0):

Investigating by setting logging: `config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "jdk");` found a WARN stating that loopback is not enabled and multicast may not work for discovery. The code below solves it and the nodes join/discover each other.

```
MulticastConfig expectedConfig = new MulticastConfig()
            .setEnabled(true)
            .setMulticastTimeoutSeconds(10)
            .setLoopbackModeEnabled(true)
            .setMulticastGroup("224.2.2.3")
            .setMulticastTimeToLive(42)
            .setMulticastPort(4242)
            .setTrustedInterfaces(newHashSet("*"));
cfg.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().setMulticastConfig(expectedConfig);
```